# TSQL Casting int when field is NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a simple query that is generating a report based on some data. If the field value is `null`, I need to enter the value of `N/A` on the report.

To do this, I do: `ISNULL(proj.projectID, 'N/A) as projectID`

This returns the error of: `Error: conversion faield when converting the varchar value 'N/A' to data type int`.

I tried to do this instead and got the same error:

`CAST(ISNULL(proj.projectID, 'N/A) as varchar) as projectID`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't have mixed datatypes in a single column. You either have to convert all your data to varchar or the preferred option would be to leave this type of formatting to the front end.

Comment: you should use `CAST` before `ISNULL`: `ISNULL(CAST(projectID AS VARCHAR(50)),'N/A')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to convert before you test isnull:

```
select ISNULL(convert(varchar(50),proj.projectID), 'N/A) as projectID
```

Comment: I agree with Avitus, that should do it. What the error is saying is that it is trying to make what is on the right side of your ISNULL, which is the "N/A" to the datatype on the left, which is an INT. It cannot do that implicitly, so it needs you to explicitly cast the ProjectID to a varchar, since you cannot explicitly cast "N/A" to an int.